# Unable to connect to any servers -cqlsh

Tags: python, cassandra, datastax-enterprise, cqlsh

I'm using Datastax cassandra 5.0.3 version.

I'm facing an issue when i try to connect to cqlsh:

```
('Unable to connect to any servers', {'10.XXX.XX.XX': UnicodeDecodeError('utf8', '\x00\x00\x88\x8f\x91\xb0Z\x7f\x00\x00\xc0BI\x03\x00\x00\x00', 2, 3, 'invalid start byte')})
```

Comment: Can you include the code that caused the error? I would guess the error is occuring somwhere here: https://github.com/datastax/python-driver/blob/8aa09c5fab6b97aa355baaa248d0df81a8e9d42e/cassandra/cluster.py#L2611-L2634 and that it might be possible that the "query" is not being encoded/decoded correctly before being sent?

Comment: I dont have any code.I'm just trying to connect to cqlsh in terminal

Comment: Can you include how you were trying to connect? The terminal version, python version and location? Maybe the command history. How were the libraries installed? Just need some context on what caused the error, or how to reproduce it.

Comment: -cqlsh hostname 9042 –u Cassandra –p password.

Comment: ~]$ python --version
Python 2.7.5

Comment: just in case please see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work Did you pip install, can you update your question with the output of `which python`, `which cqlsh`, `which pip`, I see you are using a pretty old version of python, perhaps consider upgrading?

Comment: Hi,[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.0.9.1346 | DSE 5.0.3 | CQL spec 3.4.0 | Native protocol v4]